# Node.js: A metric for how many tasks are waiting to run

Tags: node.js, monitoring

I'm running a Node.js-based web server that handles concurrent requests.  As part of monitoring the service, I'd like to know how many tasks are ready to run on the Node.js event loop.

This is sort of similar to the Linux "load average" metric.

Comment: I think the best one is the event loop delay that you can read with [node clinic](https://github.com/nearform/node-clinic)